# Use CppUnitTestFramework with VS2015 to test exe file

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, mfc, test-explorer

I have been working all day to try to get the CppUnitTestFramework to work in Visual Studio 2015 with my existing C++ MFC project, which is an exe file with graphical user interface.

I have been trying different things from this MS Guide, including "To link the tests to the object or library files" and "To add unit tests in the same project": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh419385.aspx

In the case with "To add unit tests in the same project", I just added a new unit test class in the same solution. When I compile the project the unit test just compiles fine, but it never shows up under "Test Explorer".

And in the case with "To link the tests to the object or library files", I just added a new unit test project in the same solutions. From the beginning the unit test project works fine and the sample unit test method shows up in "Test Explorer". But when I add all OBJ files from the other project (added under Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies) - and also a couple of LIB files that used by the other project are added in the same place (in total around 360 obj and lib files). And the paths are added under Linker > General > Additional Library Directories. Everything then compiles fine, but the sample unit test method disappears from the "Test Explorer". If I remove all from Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies, the sample unit test method appears in "Test Explorer" again.

[My project settings can be seen here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TF5h.png)

Anyone who has an idea as to what is going wrong, since I can not get my test methods to show up in the "Test Explorer" to test my existing project?

Comment: I have identified that the problem is probably due to some of the code under test refers on to some managed code. I have therefore tried to create a managed C ++ test project, but I still end up with, when I add my obj and lib references to my test project, then my test methods disappears from the "Test Explorer" :-(